# What type of unsolvable theory is Elementary Function Arithmetic ($EFA$)?

Tags: computability

It is known that Robinson Arithmetic ($Q$) is essentially undecidable.  Is Elementary Function Arithmetic ($EFA$) also essentially undecidable, and what is the Turing degree of its decision problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathsf{EFA}$ is a consistent computably axiomatizable theory interpreting $\mathsf{Q}$, it is also essentially undecidable and its decision problem also has Turing degree ${\bf 0'}$. Same for Peano arithmetic, $\mathsf{ZFC}$, etc.

Broadly speaking, computability-theoretic complexity is an extremely coarse invariant. Another instance of this general theme is the result that, for example, the following are equivalent for a Turing degree ${\bf d}$:

- ${\bf d}$ computes a consistent completion of $\mathsf{Q}$ *(usually "$\mathsf{PA}$" is quoted here instead of $\mathsf{Q}$, yielding e.g. the term "[$\mathsf{PA}$ degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PA_degree)," but the result holds for $\mathsf{Q}$ too)*.
- For every consistent computably axiomatizable theory $T$, ${\bf d}$ computes a consistent completion of $T$.

*(In my opinion this equivalence is demystified when we add a third equivalent condition: "${\bf d}$ computes separating sets for every pair of disjoint c.e. sets." But that's just me.)*

More fine-grained computability-theoretic distinctions can be found if we bring some semantics into play. For example, [$\mathsf{Q}$ has computable nonstandard models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic#Metamathematics) but [$\mathsf{PA}$ doesn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennenbaum%27s_theorem), and I'm not sure what the situation for $\mathsf{EFA}$ is (but I suspect it lies on the "$\mathsf{PA}$-like" side). But at least for the specific questions you've asked, all the "vaguely foundational" theories look the same.

Comment: @NoahSchwebet:  Thanks, this is helpful.

Comment: Correction:  Noah Schweber.